# How to distinct HTML select options with angularjs?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have an HTML for select tag, with this code :

```
<div ng-controller="Models">
    <select  ng-model="myModel" ng-options="Model.name for Model in Models" class="form-control"></select>
    {{ {selected_Model:myModel.name} }} {{ {selected_Model:myModel.id} }}
</div>
```

and I want it to show only `myModel.id==1`.

how can I do it ?

Answer (score 0):

I think this question needs a bit more of an explanation.

Do you mean you want to display a select for each model in models however only **if** the model.id ==1?

You can do this with a filter, while the models are being written to the page in your select box this filter checks if they have an .id == 1 and if TRUE then allows it to be written into the select.

I would imagine however that this means you'll only have 1 item in your select box as duplicate id's in objects are bad news bears.

```
angular.module('YOURAPPNAME', [])
.filter('myModelFilter', function() {
  return function(myModel) {
      if (myModel.id == 1) {
        return myModel;
      }
  };
})

<div ng-controller="Models">
    <select  ng-model="myModel" ng-options="Model.name for Model in Models | myModelFilter" class="form-control"></select>
    {{ {selected_Model:myModel.name} }} {{ {selected_Model:myModel.id} }}
</div>
```

EDIT: P.s.

Calling a controller and objects in your controllers "Model" and "Models" is confusing, I'd recommend choosing a different naming convention as AngularJS is an MVWhatever framework the term "Model" has a very different meaning to what you're using it for.

Answer (score 0):

You could this on HTML side itself by using filter with strict checking true like `ng-options="Model.name for Model in Models | filter: {id: 1}: true"`

**Markup**

```
<div ng-controller="Models">
    <select  ng-model="myModel" class="form-control"
       ng-options="Model.name for Model in Models | filter: {id: 1}: true" >
    </select>
    {{ {selected_Model:myModel.name} }} {{ {selected_Model:myModel.id} }}
</div>
```